# CiviMail SendGrid with Airmail Extension

Tags: civimail, smtp

I've had to switch away from CiviSMTP as they've gone under and I'm trying to set up an alternative. SparkPost failed as reported by others as well. I'm now trying to get SendGrid to work. I'm using it in conjunction with the Airmail Extension.

On the SMTP setup page (/civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1) test emails work fine. But neither CiviMail nor sending email via contact action are working.

With CiviMail it completes the mailing and reports 0 deliveries. All the recipients bounce with "syntax" error.

At SendGrid I've set up the webhook and tested it and it passes the test.

Any ideas.

I'm having a vague recollection that I need to allow email headers somewhere but I can't find the setting (if that is even the issue). My client needs to send out a 13K email soon so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using:

- CiviCRM 5.51.2
- Airmail 2.1
- Drupal 7.91
- php 7.4.3
- Mysql 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

Comment: Just flagging we had no issue switching to SparkPost - so not sure why it is causing others grief.

Comment: Not addressing your question directly, but I left SendGrid's shared service due to delivery problems years ago. Switched to AWS and so much better, faster and cheaper. Using this extension: https://github.com/mecachisenros/civicrm-aws

Comment: i got 404 at that link

Comment: @TimETown mis-typed the URL. Here is the correct one: https://github.com/mecachisenros/aws (the repo is called "aws" and NOT "civicrm-aws." I'll check it out and report back.

Comment: @TimETown the AWS extension's form to input AWS id and secret is not allowing any data to be entered. Arghh. I wish I wasn't using the latest version of Civi.

Comment: Sorry--the extension had the wrong link in the documentation that shows up within Civi. You can the AWS info in your civicrm.settings.php file. I can't recall everything I did, even thought I have set this up on 4 different sites! But I don't show user credentials filled. You need permission from AWS to send to other domains and can only send out from your own verified address. I let CiviCRM do tracking.

Comment: Setup can be hard work, but 10,000 emails costs $1 and they are very reliably delivered. Documentation at https://github.com/mecachisenros/aws for basic setup is good.

Comment: @Shai what problem do you have with SparkPost? its working great for us.

They also have non-profit discounts.

Comment: @themak I get one of those yellow full page error messages. The specific message is "Can't decrypt key" or something like that. This happens immediately upon enabling the extension.

Comment: @shai I tagged you on gitlab with a solution here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost/-/issues/110#note_80315

Comment: @themak Wow, thanks so much for this! I got all the way through your instructions until the last step which threw an error. I explain in the issue queue at Git lab: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost/-/issues/109#note_80674

Answer (score 1):

If it's a mail-header issue, it might be about adding the Message-ID header, which you can configure at the "CiviMail Component Settings"

/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1

That checkbox is off by default but should probably be on at this point. The box is labelled "Enable CiviMail to generate Message-ID header".

[Does gmail/google now demand a messageId?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42279/does-gmail-google-now-demand-a-messageid)

Answer (score 0):

I was a dummy and installed https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sendgrid and it works. I am also considering switching to SparkPost (assuming I can get it to work) or AWS.